# Auth fail error when using SharpSSH

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, putty, sharpssh

I am trying to connect to a `Solaris/Unix` server using a `C#` class to read system information/configuration, memory usage etc.

My requirement is to run the commands on the server from a C# application (**as we do with a `PuTTY` client**) and store the response in a `string` variable for later processing.

After some research, I found out that **`SharpSSH`** library can be used to do the same.

When I try to run my code, the following line gives me an **`Auth Fail` exception**.
I am confident that the credentials (server name, user name and password) are correct since I am able to log-in from the `PuTTY` client with the same credentials.

```
SshStream ssh = new SshStream(servername, username, password);
```

What am I doing wrong?

The following is the stack trace if it helps!

```
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect(Int32 connectTimeout)  
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect()  
at Tamir.SharpSsh.SshStream..ctor(String host, String username, String password)
```

Comment: Anything in the server side log?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Sadly, I am not used to UNIX servers, nor am I an admin. I am asked to write a program to gather these information.

Comment: Is there anything more which need to be provided so that you can have an `SSH` connection with the server (I heard something about public/private keys. I assume that is for SCP)?

Comment: SharpSSH is not up-to-date and up-to-modern-servers, so issues are possible. There exist many more viable alternatives, both free and commercial.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Can you by any chance suggest the alternatives?

Comment: SSH.NET library on Codeplex for free, our SecureBlackbox for commercial supported solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I found a VB code which pointed me to the right direction. It seems that adding an additional event handler for the `KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod` helped to solve this. Hope this helps someone else.

```
void HandleKeyEvent(Object sender, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (AuthenticationPrompt prompt in e.Prompts)
        {
            if (prompt.Request.IndexOf("Password:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
            {
                prompt.Response = password;
            }
        }
    }

private bool connectToServer()
{
    try
    {
        KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod kauth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(username);
        PasswordAuthenticationMethod pauth = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username, password);
        kauth.AuthenticationPrompt += new EventHandler<AuthenticationPromptEventArgs>(HandleKeyEvent);

        ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(serverName, port, username, pauth, kauth);

        sshClient = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
        sshClient.Connect();
        return true;
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (null != sshClient && sshClient.IsConnected)
        {
            sshClient.Disconnect();
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a little more information? What file or class did you add this code into? Thanks!

Comment: @laughsloudly I have used **SSH.NET library** from this [link](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/). I have created my own class and used `SshClient` object as a member variable.